# If $f$ is holomorphic on a compact, is $||\frac{df}{dz}||$ controlled by $||f||$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ an open set and  $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function which is injective onto its image. Suppose that $f$ is uniformly bounded on every compact subset of $U$. Then also the derivatives of $f$ will be bounded.
I would like to go a little further: is it true that if $\frac 1 c <||f'||<c$ with $c\in \mathbb{R},c>1$ close enough to $1$, then also $||f''||$ will be close to $1$? What I mean is: for every $K\subset U$ and for every $\epsilon>0$ does there exist a $\delta>0$ such that if $\frac{1}{1+\delta}<||f'(x)||<1+\delta$ for every $x \in K$ then $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}<||f''(x)||<1+\epsilon$ for every $x\in K$?

I could only think about Cauchy integral formula, but it seems useless in this case.
Do you have other ideas?

Comment: The order of quantifiers is not very precise here. Again if you look at $z+\epsilon z^2$ on the unit disk you should get a counter example. I am not sure if there is a good statement in the direction you seem to aim?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ being holomorphic on a compact set does not make sense in general. You should rather consider $f:U\rightarrow {\Bbb C}$ holomorphic on an open non-empty subset of the complex plane. If uniformly bounded then $f'$
(and any higher order derivative)  is uniformly bounded on any given compact subset of $U$. For example when using a Cauchy formula at $z$ you  need $f$ being holomorphic in a (closed) $r$-neighborhood of $z$. Not quite sure what you aim at for the second part but it seems that ( $1+\delta  \times z$) on the unit disk is a counter-example?

Comment: Injectivity does not change much. In any case you should be careful about how to define holomorphicity of  a function on a compact set (in particular without interior). And being holomorphic on say the unit disk $D$ and uniformly bounded doea not imply bounds for $f'$ on the whole disk. Only on disks of strictly smaller radii (essentially because you need the Cauchy formula on a small disk around a given point).

Comment: yes, I changed the question, I hope now it makes more sense